# Illegally fired during maternity leave, harassed to return office equipment

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, leave, rights

My company’s HR ghosted me after giving birth. I had to announce the birth of my baby and sent them some paperwork and they never replied or congratulated me. Before that, while
on sick leave due to a high risk pregnancy, they locked me out of my work email and “forgot” to pay me for a month. I had to chase them. They finally paid me but the CEO told me I was supposed to continue working during my medical leave.

Now that I’m on maternity leave, the HR manager invited me for a meeting where he informed me I was fired since the only option for me to continue working for them would be to move to another continent. Bear in mind, we all work remotely.

Now, here’s the situation. I know what they’re doing is illegal but after firing me, they immediately started contacting me by email and WhatsApp, trying to get me to return my office equipment at my own expense. I don’t remember signing anything saying it’s my responsibility for things to be returned. They locked me out of the work email so I can’t really confirm if I ever signed anything. They’ve now hired a lawyer to get me to return stuff. They’re accusing me of corporate theft. I will return everything but I need them to pay me what they’re due and also give me some paperwork so I can send it to social security. Am I being stubborn and should I just return the computer? I’m not returning it swiftly as I know they’ll immediately ghost both me and the lawyer I hired once I return things. The CEO has moved to
South America and thinks he’s untouchable. Should I return the computer and have peace of mind?

Comment: You've already hired a lawyer. Talk to them, not randoms on the Internet.

Comment: The problem is after the first expensive consultation with the lawyer via Zoom we only communicate by email and she doesn’t reply to my specific questions when I email her. She won’t reply something specific about the law when it comes to returning the office equipment.

Comment: Can you please clarify what outcome you are looking for. You said they paid you, but you need them to pay you what you are due. What are you due?

Comment: Apologies for not explaining it well. When I left on medical leave they tried not to pay me for the last month I worked for them. I chased them and they paid. That’s one situation. The second situation is that they fired me and they need to pay me a redundancy package according to my country’s laws.

Comment: You need to get a lawyer. If your office had something like a union representative, I would suggest that first, but no company behaving this way has a union representative or workers council. So there is nothing we can do for you here. You need a lawyer. Or comply with their demands. That is an economic calculation we cannot make for you, since we don't know what lawyers or oversea deliveries or your personal pride costs or is worth to you.

Comment: _"They locked me out of the work email so I can’t really confirm if I ever signed anything."_ Do not tie your recordkeeping to a mailbox that the other party has control over. You're literally giving them the key to your evidence locker. Always keep a private copy of everything you might one day need when conflicts occur.

Comment: Send back the equipment back as soon as you can. Don't use it as leverage. Just email them from your personal email and ask them for a FedEx account/UPS account/DHL account you can use to return the equipment. Ask them if they want expedited delivery, which will probably cost extra. Ask them how much insurance you should include for the delivery. And ask them about custom and duties you should prepay with their account if any. If they respond that they're not willing to pay for the shipping, respond that you can not ship it back to them and that you will be charging them for ongoing storage.

Comment: If they continue to accuse you of theft, you can threaten to drop off the equipment at the lost and found of your local police station. Then, they can work out how to get the equipment back from them. And whatever you do, do not speak to them over the phone, or via zoom, make sure all your communications are written down and timestamped.

Comment: Not off-topic. The question is "What should I do" and just because the answer is "contact a lawyer" that doesn't make the question a legal one.

Comment: Can you clarify where you are geographically, especially if it's different from your employer?

Answer (score 7):

For the legal side, you *need* to get a lawyer. You canot go unarmed into a gunfight. They already have a lawyer.

I will assume some things here: the equipment is indeed *their* equipment. There is no doubt, they sent it to you in the first place. And it is a laptop or computer or other technical devices, not just a bunch of pencils and a notebook.

That said, you have to find out, if hiring a lawyer is worth it. What *are* the shipping costs? If the shipping costs are 100$ and a lawyer costs 200$ an hour just for a first consultation, maybe the better way is to give in and pay it and be done with it. Legal battles can be long and if you pay 1000$ to win and not have to pay 100$ shipping fees, that is a phyrric victory.

So far I would (actually did) vote to close your question, because you need a real life actual law professional with a letterhead in communication and a law degree in your country or theirs. However, I would like to offer one last chance to get out of it, because it occurred to me just when I went to grab a coffee after voting to close:

Assuming their equipment to be returned is indeed a computer or part that uses a lithium-ion battery, go to the post office and read the customs guidelines for your country. In my country, private persons *cannot* ship lithium ion bateries overseas. They *cannot*. It's not allowed. Customs/Security won't let you. They would flat out reject the package. The only way as a private person to ship a lithiom ion battery is to prove that it is company equipment (for example showing the delivery documents) and then have a company ordered courier service pick it up from you. In other words, where I live, due to customs and safety concerns, you, the *employee* cannot, I repeat *cannot* ship this equipment. The company has to pay someone to pick it up.

This is not just paperwork, I actually tried 3 years ago to sent a computer from Europe back to the US and I had the package returned, even when the post office lady was fine with it and it was clearly labelled containing lithium ion batteries, it came back as customs/safety inspections wouldn't allow it on board a plane. Not from a private person.

So... check if that applies in your country (I would assume it's some global safety standard for cargo aircraft, we don't make up our own local rules what we put into other countries transport planes I hope). If it does, write them a neutral letter saying you will give them their equipment when they sent a courier, but they need to pay the pickup service, because it just won't work any other way legally.

---

Otherwise, the smart choice is still to get a lawyer. This is a fringe edge case. It might not apply to you, your country or the equipment in question.

Comment: You're going to need a lawyer anyway to deal with the illegal firing. Getting advice about the equipment is a very small additional cost.

Comment: The reason is they have to fly the package. Lithium is banned from shipping via flight. In the USA, ground shipping is fine to ship batteries but you can't ship it overnight, for example, as it will go on an airplane. Most likely the battery is safe but since it has a potential of being unstable if hit or dropped, it's better they just didn't include it at all.